# Resources for learning European Portuguese

Tags: discussion, recursos

Based on feedback I've received from native Portuguese speakers, it seems that most of the online or other language learning resources I've found teach Brazilian Portuguese. However, despite living closer to Brazil myself, my intent for learning is so that I can properly interact with people who actually are in Portugal.

Could someone give me a pointer to materials that teach proper European Portuguese? Interactive courses (a-la Duolingo) are preferred, but at this point I'll pretty much settle for anything. Also, of course, there's no better price than "free".

I'm posting here on Meta because I didn't think this would be a suitable question for the main site. Feel free to migrate if appropriate.

Comment: I am Portuguese, and Brazilians have been properly interacting with me for ages, so I wouldn't worry too much about it. Standard, educated, language is basically the same in both countries. The grammar I find in Brazilian sites is with few exceptions the one followed in Portugal too. It's the colloquial language that can diverge. Of course, for Portugal you need the canonical verb conjugation with *tu* ―tu vais, tu és, tu tens, etc.―that few Brazilians use. Accent here is very different from Brazil's too. Unfortunately I don’t know any online learning stuff.

Comment: I understand that the two dialects are mutually intelligible. However, I believe it is more appropriate for me to learn the form that would be most familiar to those with whom I expect to converse regularly. Certainly, in my home area, I am more often surrounded by Brazilians than I am Portuguese. However, I am more interested in speaking Portuguese with my Portuguese friends than I am with the random stranger on the street here.

Comment: I found this [memrise](https://www.memrise.com/courses/english/portuguese-portugal-2/). Don't know whether it is any good though. At what stage are you? Do you speak a little?

Comment: @Jacinto Thanks for the pointer. I'm pretty much starting at zero with Portuguese.

Comment: @Iszi I found that site: https://www.practiceportuguese.com it seems nice.